# How to schedule a windows task to repeat every day within a time range?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

In Windows 7, how to schedule a task which repeats every hour, every day but within a time range. I have a script which needs to run everyday from 08:00 to 20:00 in 1 hour interval.Could not find any solution even after googling.Anybody tried something similar? Any hints?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Task Scheduler does this all by itself...  When you add a trigger to tell the task when to run, it's available as an advanced option.

[image: Trigger Options]

Answer (score 5):

The 12 hour duration each day is supported in the UI, for others you need to use the command line. You set the recur to daily and the repeat + duration for how often and for how long you want the tasks to run during that day.

[image]

The trigger summary ends up as:

[image]

Comment: No need to use the command line, just type `7 hours` (or whatever you need) in for the duration (or `repeat every` field).

Comment: I can't get these settings to work. The task runs after the 12:th iteration until the next day. I have the same exact settings but I'm running Windows 2008 server. Any ideas?

Comment: `The 12 hour duration each day is supported in the UI, for others you need to use the command line`.  any simple using ***command line*** for 20 hours duration each day, one execution each hour?

Answer (score 2):

You could look into the "schtask" command on the command promt (if you type help on command prompt you will see it listed). Assuming I understand your question correctly, this is what you want to type:

> schtasks /create /tn *(whatever Task Name you want to call it)* /tr *(location full of the file)* /sc hourly /st 08:00:00 /et 20:00:00 /sd *(start date that you want mm/dd/yyyy)*

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using Windows Scheduled Tasks?